# How to run a command without terminal in rust?

Tags: user-interface, rust, tauri

I researched quite a lot about this, and didn't find a solution. I need to run binaries(on windows .exe) in tauri GUI application. The problem is that when I do it *in dev mode*, I *don't see windows* of terminals appearing, I suppose that's because I run it through terminal(`cargo tauri dev`). However, in release mode I do.

I need a solution to either have this window hid, or not shown. Maybe I should run it in a seperate thread, maybe I should hide it with some command by process id, or even create my own minimal terminal emulator. I really have no more idea how to fix that. Please, help me.

If you need more information, just tell me and I will give anything you need.

P.s I can't integrate this executable into my code because it's proprietary and likely written in c++.

Here's what *I have tried*:

```rust
/* 
ALL Don't work

#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]
#![cfg_attr(windows_subsystem = "windows")]
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]

*/




fn main() {
    <...>
}
```

Here's my code:

```rust
// src-tauri/main.rs

#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]

mod my_class;
// <...>

#[tauri::command]
fn my_actual_handler(some_var: &str) {
    let my_class = MyClass::new(some_var);
    my_class.execute();
}

fn main() {
    <...>
    tauri::Builder::default().handlers(my_actual_handler).run();
}
```

```rust
// src-tauri/my_class.rs

pub struct MyClass {
    some_var: String,
    child: child: RwLock<Option<Child>>,
}

impl MyClass {
   <...>
   
    pub fn execute(&self) {
        let child = Command::new(env::current_dir().unwrap().join("my_app.exe"))
            .arg("some args")
            .arg(
                env::current_dir()
                    .unwrap()
                    .join("data")
                    .join(format!("{}.json", "more data")),
            )
            // .stdout(Stdio::piped()) - tried solution, and null() too
            // .stderr(Stdio::piped()) - tried solution, and null() too
            .spawn()
            .expect("ERROR: Failed to start the child process");
        
        /* I need this to be able to stop the child in the future, if you have an idea how to do this in a better way, please tell me */
        let mut child_lock = self.child.write().expect("RwLock write lock failed");
        *child_lock = Some(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will want to capture the output of that process, as well as wait around for it to finish. Perhaps release mode runs so quickly that it gets ahead of the other process, while for whatever reason, the debug build is just slow enough the subprocess has a chance to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by passing the [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags#flags) flag to [`Command::creation_flags`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/windows/process/trait.CommandExt.html#tymethod.creation_flags):

```
const CREATE_NO_WINDOW: u32 = 0x08000000;

let child = Command::new(env::current_dir().unwrap().join("my_app.exe"))
    .arg("some args")
    .arg(
        env::current_dir()
            .unwrap()
            .join("data")
            .join(format!("{}.json", "more data")),
    )
    .creation_flags (CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    .spawn()
    .expect("ERROR: Failed to start the child process");
```